# How can I make a shared library's symbols strong?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I have a shared library that I've created that references a lot of C++ template functions. These symbols get entered into the shared library's export table as weak references (e.g. they show as type `W` when I view the shared library's symbols using `nm`). This means that at runtime, these symbols can possibly be interposed by copies from a different shared library that got loaded first.

It's important for my application that my shared library use the copies of these functions that are contained within the library itself, not from any other library. Is there any way to ensure this? It sounds to me like it would be tantamount to statically linking all of the various template instantiations into the shared library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This means that at runtime, these symbols can possibly be interposed
>   by copies from a different shared library that got loaded first.

Note that they can be interposed regardless of weak attribute (see [this GCC post](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2011-03/msg00217.html) which says that dynamic linker treats weaks similar to strongs, unless `LD_DYNAMIC_WEAK` is set, which usually isn't).

> It's important for my application that my shared library
>   use the copies of these functions that are contained
>   within the library itself, not from any other library.
>   Is there any way to ensure this?

There are several things you can do.

The usually recommended approach is to add `fvisibility=hidden` to your CFLAGS to prevent exporting any symbols from your library and then mark the (hopefully very few) exported functions with `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`. This would also allow for better optimization at compile-time and faster start-up as rtld will need to process fewer symbols.

A poor man's limited solution would be to employ `-fvisibility-inlines-hidden` which is a limited form of `-fvisility=hidden`. It will only hide inline functions (e.g. resulting from STL templates).

In case you do not want to mess with source code, link with `-Wl,-Bsymbolic` - this would force references to be resolved within the library whenever possible.

-- EDIT --

Actually you'll need `-Bsymbolic` even if you enable `-fvisibility=hidden` to prevent other libraries (or executable itself) from dynamically interposing intra-library references to exported functions.

Comment: Thanks. `-Bsymbolic` and/or `-Bsymbolic-functions` are solutions to my problem. I think I will probably do the recommended approach of rigorously defining the public API and using `-fvisibility=hidden`, though. It seems to be the best practice.

Comment: On second thought I think you'll need `-Bsymbolic` even with `-fvisibility=hidden` - without it exported functions can be interposed by other shared libraries. Also to avoid messing with `fvisibility=hidden` you can use it's simpler variant `-fvisiblity-inlines-hidden` - this would hide all inline functions (including STL templates). I've updated the answer.